# Why do the top and bottom margins disappear in the child container?

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
    Hi
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.child {
  background-color: #999999;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

When this renders, the top and bottom margin on the child div is missing.
After applying the following styles to the `.parent` class, margins reappear. Why is this?

```
.parent {
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/trxek0kc/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some cases, top and bottom margins are collapsed. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing). What's happening is this:

> If there is no border, padding, inline part, block formatting context created, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block, [...] then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Hey If I understand correctly, You have to add padding to parent element rather than giving margin to the child element. Then you will get your desired result.

```
.parent {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  padding: 20px;
}

.child {
  background-color: #999999;

}
```

or you can add add overflow property to parent element

```
.parent {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not missing but it's applied to the body,

see more details here : [collapsing margins](https://www.sitepoint.com/collapsing-margins/)

> In simple terms, this definition indicates that when the vertical margins of two elements are touching, only the margin of the element with the largest margin value will be honored,